# Having an Object Rotate and Look at the center of the screen (Third person game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to get my character to point its cannon to the center of the screen so it can shoot accurately. This game is going to be a third person game so keep that in mind. I'm fairly new to coding so if you can help it would be awesome!

```
void Update()
{

    //Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); (not sure if I should use this)
    float midPoint = (transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position).magnitude * 0.5f;

    transform.LookAt(midPoint);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shoot in the Center of the Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856805/shoot-in-the-center-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Vector3 screenPos = new Vector2(Screen.width /2.0f, Screen.height/2.0f,0);

Vector3 worldPos = ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);
```

will get the center of the screen as a point in the world, however it will be on the veiw plane right next to the camera

you could get something to look at this point with

```
object.transform.LookAt(worldPos);
```

however if you want it to point at whatever the camera is looking at,  you can raycast along this line like

```
Raycast(worldPos, Camera.main.transform.forward);
```

and then look at whatever that hits

Comment: Thanks Jake this helped a ton!